# Does every EC2 instance has "Instance Store Volume"?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Does every EC2 instance has "Instance Store Volume"? When I am trying to create a t2.micro instance, I could not able to add "Instance Store Volume"

Comment: The prices page and documentation clearly state that only certain instance types have instance stores.

Answer (score 2):

> Does every EC2 instance has "Instance Store Volume"?

No, they do not. Only certain Instance type can be allocated instance stores. See the [EC2 Instance Types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) page. Many types listed there are "EBS Only" (including the t2.micro that you are trying to create), meaning instance store volumes are not possible.